# Current est time in java with daylight saving

Tags: java, date, time

I stumbled upon this piece of code to get current time in EST with daylight saving. It seems to work fine, when checked on the internet by the time displayed in sites providing current time in EST with daylight saving.

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
  dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST5EDT")); 
  System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

I just want to confirm, has anybody used something like this before or there is a better way to achieve the same. I cannot use **Joda library** due to constraints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: little more research even this gives same result TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern")

Comment: @user458248 how did you get that timezone id (EST5EDT)? I don't seem to find it in the java docs.

Comment: @asgs its long time back cant recall, found in some code snippet while googling

Comment: TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() is a String Array that contains all the list of timezone ids. You can loop it to display all and check it in the output

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the best (and indeed the only) way to do this using Java's standard libraries.